# Validar una dirección de billetera con expresiones regulares

Tags: python, regex

Necesito validar una dirección de billetera de criptomoneda en la red de smart chain  (en el sentido de que este bien escrita, no necesariamente que sea verdadera ) mediante expresiones regulares, preferiblemente en código en Python. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea o recomendación?

Ejemplo de dirección de billetera:

0xF599F7b9d15DA9DfC3F0FB059Fa1393b5d4826fF

El código podría quedar algo asi:

```
import re
def esUnaWalletCorrectaEnTransaccion_USDT_BET20(supuestaWallet):
    return re.match(r"^patron que necesito$", supuestaWallet) is not None
```

Mi aplicación pide para poder realizar un pago que le pasen la dirección, el código seria para antes de almacenar los datos, comprobar que son correctos (al menos en estructura ) y evitar futuros errores

Comment: Lo siento, si mi pregunta puede parecerte un poco tonta. Pero tengan paciencia conmigo, solo estoy aprendiendo. Entonces, lo que quiero saber es si puedes crear una billetera directamente a cambio.

Comment: No estoy seguro, porque el comercio de criptomonedas también es nuevo para mí. Me registré en [https://www.cryptomkt.com/es-cl/polygon-matic](https://www.cryptomkt.com/es-cl/polygon-matic) e intentaré aprender este mecanismo. No soy ese programador experimentado o usuario de computadoras para codificar nada yo mismo. No en este momento al menos. Pero gracias por este ayudante. Espero usarlo en el futuro.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta @Sandy Flies , dices que si se puede crear una billetera electrónica solo a partir de código, por ejemplo python?

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré una respuesta

```
import re
def esUnaWalletCorrectaoEnTransaccion_USDT_BET20(supuestaWallet):
    return re.match(r"^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$", supuestaWallet) is not None
```

- Comienzan con 0x
- Después de eso son 40 caracteres hexadecimales (a-f, A-F, and 0-9)

La respuesta la encontré en estos links:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/what-is-the-regex-to-validate-an-ethereum-transaction-hash/34286

https://regexland.com/regex-ethereum-addresses/